# 403 Forbidden when requesting image from server

Tags: css, apache

I have a static resource image on my static server (http://static.coderichard.com/) which I want to use for a Journal Skin which I'm designing on DeviantArt. But when the image is loaded, I got a 403 Forbidden error.

The image is loaded through CSS like so:

```
background-image: url('http://static.coderichard.com/img/intrvi-journal-skin-bg.png');
```

When I tried the exact same thing in JSFiddle, it worked fine. I can also load the image through the browser.

Checking error logs yielded no information and the directory the image is in has 755 permission.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I read the following thread, having the same issue as me: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2167595
The solution was to disable the hotlink protection via .htaccess, but I don't have a .htaccess file there so it makes no sense to try that.

Comment: First thing I'd do is try another image from another url (not your server) to see if it's your server or DeviantArt that's causing the issue

Comment: I can see that you are using CloudFlare - have you enabled the hotlink protection feature?

Comment: @RobFarr I may have. And if I did I'm going to feel very stupid.

Comment: @RichardA It may not be that, have another look at your settings just to make sure though :)

Comment: @RobFarr your suggestion helped me fix it. :)

Comment: @RichardA Thats good!! - if you want to you could always add an answer to the question yourself to help out anyone else facing a similar problem in the future :)

Comment: @RobFarr I did, have a look. :)

Comment: @RichardA Thanks, my bad for not seeing that you had done it :P

Comment: @RobFarr Hakuna Matata. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My server is CloudFlare protected and uses Hotlink protection. What I did to fix it was add a directory called hotlink-ok and I put all my resources there which were okay to hotlink.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a referer with a commannd-line client. If it immediately 403s again, find where your "hotlink protection" is implemented.